# Using VHD as SD card with android-x86 on Hyper-v

Tags: android-emulator, hyper-v, android-x86

I have created and android-x86 4.4 vm running on hyper-v. I attached an additional hard disk on the IDE 1 controller to the virtual machine. I open GRUB and add SDCARD=/sda2/ I don't see this SD card mounted when VM starts up. I have used df and mount command, still don't see the new hard drive appear in the output. Any ideas on troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/sdcardhowto), you need to create a `fat/msdos filesystem` and mount it using [vold](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-1658/6mhcgsu31/index.html).